# Is it somehow possible to read a .rar or a .zip file inside the windows phone 7? How?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xna, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm trying to create a Windows Phone 7 application, using either Silverlight or XNA, but I can't figure out how to do such thing, that would be part of the idea of the app. If it is not possible, is there any kind of format that does something similar to that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need to implement your own zip compressor or download some and add to app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read a zip file **if** you have prior knowledge of the folders and files  it contains.  In fact MSDN contains an example of doing that when discussing the [Application.GetResourceStream(StreamResourceInfo, Uri)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190632%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method.

Alternatively you can use [slsharpzlib](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/) if you need to explore and extract (and indeed create) zip files.

Comment: @Bruno: to which of the two approaches are you refering?  If the latter, that would be a shame, it claims that it does.  If it doesn't I don't know of any alternative.

Comment: Should point out that slssharpzlib is GPL licensed so probably not appropriate for commercial app development.

Answer (score 1):

[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) is implemented purely in C# and has been ported to the Compact Framework, so you could probably use it.  Commercial libraries you have to be careful with becasue they may use P/Invokes to the zlib stuff for speed, which is going to fail under WinPhone.

**EDIT**

I see SharpZipLib has already been ported.  See AnthonyWJones's answer.